# How can i share text and image in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I want share my application's content (**Text and Image**) and for this issue, I wrote below codes:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("*/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(content) + "" +"\n\n" + "download us app from this link" + "\n\n" +"https://play.google.com/app/com.example.example");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "select app ..."));
```

But in this code, I can just share text not sharing image! I want to share Text and Image.

For show Text and Image, I use `Webview`. I show image into text in `webview`.

How can I share Text and Image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below code is useful to share both text and images with other apps.

```
String imageToShare = "http://s1.dmcdn.net/hxdt6/x720-qef.jpg"; //Image You wants to share

String title = "Title to share"; //Title you wants to share

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, imageToShare);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Select App to Share Text and Image"));
```

Comment: Dear Is Not Work for me ...I have Two TextView and ImageUrl but I can share One TextView To Telegram

Answer (score 0):

See below Code,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/png");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/");//your Image Url
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: I want show image from internet not save it. how can it?

Comment: @KirKoloft, Now I updated my answer, Its work for me

Answer (score -1):

Add the URI of your image to the bundle (e.g. http://some.server.com/your_image.png), this will allow the same image to be found & used when the data is pulled out of the bundle.

Comment: This does not provide any useful information